# Select which radio button is checked based from database value Django

Tags: python, django

I have an html table which is populated based from the value in database.

How can i set which radio button is selected based from the database value in form load. I have tried the code below but it is not checking anything. Thanks

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"><h4>Id</h4></th>
                        <th scope="col"><h4>Requirement Name</h4></th>
                        <th scope="col"><h4>Remarks</h4></th>
                        <th scope="col"><h4>Date Promised</h4></th>
                        <th scope="col"><h4>Completed</h4></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {% for req in requirements %}
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="hidden" name="requirements_id_{{req.pk}}" value="{{ req.pk }}"><span>{{ req.pk }}</span></th>
                        <th><span>{{ req.requirement }}</span></th>
                        <th><textarea rows="1" cols="35" name="requirements_remarks_{{req.pk}}">{{ req.remarks }}</textarea></th>
                        <th><input type="date" name="requirements_date_promised_{{req.pk}}" value="{{ req.date_promised|date:'Y-m-d' }}"></th>
                        <th><input type="radio" name="requirements_completed_{{req.pk}}" value="{{ req.completed }}"> No
                            <input type="radio" name="requirements_completed_{{req.pk}}" value="{{ req.completed }}"> Yes</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: A radio button's checked state is controlled via the "checked" property. See: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: can you show forms.py code

Comment: yes. but how i can set a condition in django to write a "checked" based from the database value.

Comment: @c.grey i am manually populating it without using the forms in django. it is somehow still posible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set which radio button is selected without using a Django form, you can apply some logic to each radio button which sets the `checked` attribute. Note that you should also ensure that the `value` attribute is unique for each element:

```
<th><input type="radio" name="requirements_completed_{{req.pk}}" value="no"{% if not req.completed %} checked{% endif %}> No
    <input type="radio" name="requirements_completed_{{req.pk}}" value="yes"{% if req.completed %} checked{% endif %}> Yes</th>
```